# Flutter:how play video in background mode?

Tags: android, flutter, video, flutter-video-player

I want to play a video in backg mode in flutter. actually i want to play video even my phone is locked ,i know exo play can play a video in background service.
but I dont know how ply a video in background service
can help me ?

Comment: Do you want to play a video which is already on the phone, do you want to download it or do you want to use an external service such as youtube?

Comment: @FrontMobe hi thanks . i want play a video from internet.but i want to video be play in back mode even phone is locked.do you know abot it?thanks

Comment: Sorry if I still do not answer the question. But the internet is a large space. Which service do you want to use to play the video in the first place?

Comment: @FrontMobe i  want to play a mp4 video from my server but i want video player be can play my video in background mod.like a media player can play music in background mod.but i dont know how can i do that.if you know please help me.thanks